# How can I use an unstyled select element in a page with Materialize?

Tags: css, materialize

I have a page (ASP.NET/C#) with Materialize and all works fine.  I am in need to add a dropdown combobox control that is NOT styled with Materialize, I just want a plain, vanilla combobox with no styling.  Using the class "browser-default" still has many materialize styling elements applied to it. Is there a way to completely ignore any styling from materialize on a component.

```
<select id="myBareComponent" class="browser-default">
  <option value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Two">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

That certainly is a heavy-handed approach to CSS on the part of the Materialize team. You may have to do some reset work for the `.browser-default` class:

```
select.browser-default {
    background-color: initial;
    width: auto;
    padding: unset;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just as I was sitting here looking at the selector overrides thinking the same thing :D +1

Comment: fwiw, doing that reset work requires an "!important" on every line, else Materialize's heavy hand prevails!

Comment: There's probably a better way, such as prefixing with `body `. I avoid `!important` like the corona virus.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to utilize JavaScript to [get the computed style of an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and then iterate over the computed style to remove every styling. Not sure if this breaks the element though! You can also filter for individual style attributes, if you need that:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#myBareComponent')
for (const attribute in window.getComputedStyle(select)) {
  switch (attribute) {
    case 'display':
      select.style['display'] = 'none' // select.style['display'] == select.style.display
      break
    default:
      select.style[attribute] = ''
      break
  }
}
```